# Using the Begingroup Extension of MathJax?

Tags: bug, mathjax

I noticed that the site does not seem to use the [begingroup extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#begingroup) for MathJax, which could *possibly* lead to bugs: For example, a macro defined in a comment to a question could have an unexpected affect on an answer below it.

Comment: I believe that we have seen the effect of this in chat. `\newcommand` appearing in a comment persists until that statement rolls off the scrollback. This can mess up the $\LaTeX$ later on if the command is not done right. We have unofficially outlawed `\newcommand` etc. In chat.

Comment: This has been discussed before.

Comment: A related discussion: [The scope of \newcommand is the entire page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page). [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/poll-for-mathjax-macros-that-should-be-automatically-loaded/3727#3727) is a poll, where you can vote which extensions should be included, in your opinion.